# Hide web part on Sharepoint 2013 page on certain day

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I have to hide one web part on page or whole page (whatever I find quicker) on every Friday. I made javascript code few months ago to hide web parts after 10AM, so I edited that code for new purpose.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
 var currentDay = new Date();
 var day = currentDay.getDay();
 var hideMe = document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3");  
 /* This is web part that I need to hide */

if(day=3) { /* I put 3 for today to check if it will work, but I need Friday as a day */
 hideMe.style.display = "none";          
}
else {
 hideMe.style.display = "block";
}
}, false);
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: It didn't work. I put == instead of =. Now it works. Solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put == instead of = inside If clause

```
if(day==3)
```

and now it works.